# Is it possible to connect different springs to the same node in abaqus

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to model a simple timber connection with a slotted-in steel plat in abaqus using the beam on foundation modelling approach. In this modelling approach the embedment behavoiur of the timber is modelled using springs elements. In this simple example that I am trying to study, a dowel type fastener is modelled using circular elastoplatic beam elements. The slotted-in steel plate and the timber surrounding it is modelled using elastic beam elements. The interaction between the timber parts and the dowel is modelled using spring elements. See the following figure.
[Modelling of the connection. From Romain Lemitre PhD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6lFA.png)

My question is the following. Is it possible to connect different spring nodes to one node in the elastoplatic dowel in abaqus as indicated in the following figure.
[Connecting different springs to the same node in the elastoplatic beam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEokH.png)

I tried to simply connect differnt springs nodes to the same node in the beam. But it does not seem to be allowed.